# No gazebo-ros package after update?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After the recent 2.0.0 Gazebo update, I can no longer run gazebo_ros. It has been deinstalled during the update. When trying to install gazebo-ros-pkgs, I get the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control : Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
 ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs : Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When trying to install the mentioned ros-hydro-gazebo-ros, this is the output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-gazebo-ros : Depends: gazebo but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Yet, gazebo is installed and can be run.

Is there something broken in the repository?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4653/no-gazebo-ros-package-after-update?/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/519/rafberkvens/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-10-22**:
i have this problem also!

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-22**:
The repository was somewhat broken during some hours, it should be fixed now. Try to uninstall gazebo package and read the instructions to use [Gazebo with ROS](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install/Gazebo_and_ROS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This [issue](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/126) is tracking the problem. The problem should be resolved very soon.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-10**:
As Nate said, it should happen very soon, but some more information and workaround are covered in [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4630/problem-with-loading-gazebo-in-ros/?answer=4672).

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/519/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-11**:
Thanks for both the reply and the comment. I'm now waiting for the actual update to happen.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-22**:
For problems related to Gazebo and ROS, be sure to read the [Gazebo/ROS integration document](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install/Gazebo_and_ROS)